# UICollectionView didselect doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview, reloaddata, didselectrowatindexpath

Everytime I press a cell I want the cell to change image:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {

      if ([[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item] isEqual: @"dog.png"]) {
          [arrayOfImages replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.item withObject:@"cat.png"];

      } else if ([[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item] isEqual: @"cat.png"]) {
          [arrayOfImages replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.item withObject:@"lion.png"];

      } else if ([[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item] isEqual: @"lion.png"]) {
          [arrayOfImages replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.item withObject:@"dog.png"];

      }

    [myCollectionView reloadData];
  }
```

I press a cell and nothing happen, now if I press another cell, the previous one changes image and the same thing happens for every cell I press. The image that change is always the image of the previous cell. It's like it doesn't update the collectionView since I press again the collectionView.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have implemented `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` not `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, thus when you select an other cell the cell you selected first gets deselected and triggers the `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

wrong method used.it is `didSelectItemAtIndexpath` to be defined for the purpose not `didDeselect`